# Python - How to apply values from other columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to insert a new column called "Sponsor" and the values of this column comes from multiple columns.

**> Current Data**

```
Program    Source      Region  Owner
    A       Global        ECAN   Girl
    B       Regional       US    Boy
    C       Delta Global  EMEA   Girl
```

**> Insert Sponsor column and the values should be based on below logic**

If, Program == "A" OR Program == "B" AND Source column contains "Global" then use the value from Owner column Else return the same value from Source column

I tried in below format but little confused

```
def SetSponsor(row):
    if str(row['Source']).contains('Global') & (row['Program'] == 'A') | (row['Program'] == 'B') : 
        return (row['Owner'])
    else :
    return (row['Source'])
                
df['Sponsor'] = df.apply(lambda row: SetSponsor(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: Don't reask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75163831/how-to-apply-values-based-on-multiple-columns

Comment: Dont follow me please. Below solution worked for me. You already devoted my post and following me here. You seem to be upset with something. I really wanted help and finally it got solved here. Please get back to your day. Bye

Comment: I'm not following you. Your question showed up on the front page. The question I linked in your other post does answer your question -- your code where you check if "global" is in the string is wrong. I didn't see your comment saying you didn't understand the link. If I had, I'd give you some more pointers there. The answer here takes a completely different (but more efficient) approach to yours, but I guess that doesn't really matter if all you care about is "a way to do X" instead of learning why your approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for complex conditions.

- `contains` function requires *string* context: `str.contains()`
- to check if an element is contained in list of values is convenient with `Series.isin(values)` function

---

```
df['Sponsor'] = np.where((df['Source'].str.contains('Global')) & (df['Program'].isin(['A','B'])),
                         df['Owner'], df['Source'])
```

---

```
  Program        Source Region Owner       Sponsor
0       A        Global   ECAN  Girl          Girl
1       B      Regional     US   Boy      Regional
2       C  Delta Global   EMEA  Girl  Delta Global
```